# Project half made in mysql & half in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working on this project in php. Half of the project has been done using `mysql_query` and the newest modules have been made using `mysqli`. There a lot of modules and i don't want to change the code. Will it create problems if is like this. Or should i convert it all to `mysqli`. I would be grateful if somebody suggest me whats the right method?

Comment: You will have to. Cause mysql is deprecated and will be removed in one of the next versions of PHP. So your modules work then anymore either.

Comment: It will also be a lot more difficult to maintain in the future, because you'll inevitably end up with script execution that (mis)combines both and returns no results.... witness the number of questions that crop up each day here doing exactly that

Comment: You should decide for one of them because of consistency, but i don't think there will be any problems to use both.

Comment: There is at least 3 years to mysql is being removed from a future version of PHP (5.5 is supported 3 years after release) and it is not sure at all that mysql will be removed after 3 years. But _eventually_ it will. Just saying ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the best way to handle this properly is to create your own thin database layer and encapsulate calls to mysql_query in your own functions.

Also, another option is to switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is a bit nicer, as it supports 
named parameters and more databases. Here's a [comparison between mysqli and PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).